# VS Code Flow-Language-Support Failed to Start: Couldn't find version of '../node_modules/flow-bin/flow-linux64-v0.174.1/flow'

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, flowtype, vscode-remote

So I'm using VSCode coupled with the VSCode remote server sitting on my VM. I'm trying to use the Flow-Language-Support plugin, but I get the following error.

```
Failed to Start: Couldn't find version of '../node_modules/flow-bin/flow-linux64-v0.174.1/flow'
```

I'm not much sure what to make of it. I tried adding...

```
[version] 
0.174.1
```

...to my `.flowconfig` but it didn't do anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using an absolute path instead of a relative one.